# Text shifted in sub-tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using `tikz` to produce figures composed of multiple more or less complex subfigures that appear multiple times. So I created a command to produce a `tikzpicture` block for the subfigure, and now I want to call it twice in a wrapping `tikzpicture`.

Below is a MWE, could someone explain why the label is shifted in the second square? Should I change the `pos=0.5` for something else? It looks like it is a consequence of the `anchor=north west`, but I don't know how to get the behavior I'm looking for (i.e. same positioning, but both labels centered inside the squares).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\drawSquare}{ m }{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (#1,-#1) node [pos=.5] {$A$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[](S) { \drawSquare{2} };
        \node[anchor=north west](T) at ([xshift=1cm]S.north east) { \drawSquare{2} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the corresponding pdf image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I cannot offer a profound explanation except pointing out that:

- It is dangerous to nest `tikzpicture`s. As far as I know it is not "officially" supported. It often works, but sometimes it does not, because some setting or parameter of the outer picture interferes with the inner one. In your case the anchor of the outer node interferes with the positioning of the inner node. In the example below, the blue rectangle (a picture within a node) is still ok, but the additional anchoring (red rectangle) breaks the positioning of the inner node.
- When you pack material into a node, you have to be careful if you want to position it precisely. Observe that the red rectangle is not positioned exactly at the coordinate. The reason is that the contents is surrounded by an inner and an outer border. Only after setting these to zero (`inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt`), the corner of the rectangle is at the coordinate (green rectangle). Moreover, observe that the label (the green 4) is still off the center, but it has moved compared to the red 3 in the other rectangle; it is hard to predict what happens with nested tikzpictures.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2) node[pos=.5] {$1$};
   \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (2pt);
   %
   \node[blue] at (3,0)
     {\tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2) node[pos=.5] {$2$};};
   \draw[blue,fill] (3,0) circle (2pt);
   %
   \node[red,anchor=south west] at (4,0)
     {\tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2) node[pos=.5] {$3$};};
   \draw[red,fill] (4,0) circle (2pt);
   %
   \node[green,anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (6,0)
     {\tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2) node[pos=.5] {$4$};};
   \draw[green,fill] (6,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the real application, the subfigures are of course more complex, and I thought it was great to have them included in a node, so that you can e.g. resize a whole subfigure if needed. But maybe it's possible to do all that without multiple tikzpicture. Thank you for these proposals, I didn't know all these alternatives.

Comment: @Zooky Including the sub-pictures in a node means that you give up possibilities to interact with the sub-picture, and to influence it.

Comment: Yes, but consider that the two pictures have different (and unknown) widths and heights. It believe it is convenient to use anchors with respect to these sub-pictures, not sure it's easy otherwise. Suppose you want to reuse \drawSquare to draw two squares of sizes 2x2 and 3x3 that are aligned on their bottom edge rather than on the top edge, and 2cm apart from each other. Then you will need to calculate explicitly the position at which you want to draw the squares (which in this case is easy, but we might want to avoid that in practice, especially if we don't know the dimensions).

Comment: @Zooky You are right, in such a context anchors may be reasonable. The real problem is the nesting of pictures. I have rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did.

I removed the north-west anchor and drawn the picture `east` w.r.t. the first.

Here is the code

```
            \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \usepackage{xparse}

            \DeclareDocumentCommand{\drawSquare}{ m }{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw (0,0) rectangle (#1,-#1) node [pos=.5] {$A$};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
            \begin{document}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node[](S) { \drawSquare{2} };
                    \node[](T) at ([xshift=2.2cm]S.east) { \drawSquare{2} };
                \end{tikzpicture}
             \end{document}
```

And here the result:

[image]

Comment: In practice my subfigures are way more complicated, and in particular do not have the same height. Is there a way to adapt this code to have the figures "top-justified"? Thanks.

Comment: I fear this will not always work in certain circumstances since `\DeclareDocumentCommand` is not expandable.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just took it from OP. But thanks for the remark!